# Disassemble i386 in Raspbian?

Tags: assembly

I want to disassemble i386 machine instructions into human readable text in Raspbian.

I am a rookie Linux user and don't know the configuration of installed tools, but from what I understand I need an architecture for i386 for objdump.

```
objdump -D -b binary -mi386 -Maddr16,data16 binfile

    binfile: file format binary

    objdump: can't use supplied machine i386
```

Indeed, looking at the supported architectures in objdump, I can see i386 is not included.

```
objdump: supported architectures: arm armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 
         armv4t armv5 armv5t armv5te xscale ep9312 iwmmxt iwmmxt2 plugin
```

How can I add i386 architecture to the list of supported architectures? Is it a pluggable definition I can just download and place in a particular location? Or do I need to modify and make a new objdump executable?

Comment: llvm-objdump may be able to (depending, I think, on how it was built). `llvm-objdump --version` will tell you.

Comment: Thank you @greggo, but it does not appear to be installed in Raspbian GNU/Linux 8(jessie) by default. I'll look into obtaining this tool once I figure out where and how I can obtain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried it, but there is [a `binutils-multiarch` package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/binutils-multiarch) "used to manipulate binary and object files that may have been created on other architectures".  It includes an `objdump` which from the looks of things will replace the existing one.  The other files [are listed here.](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/binutils-multiarch/filelist)

So, worth trying:

```
apt-get install binutils-multiarch
```

And seeing if the new `objdump` meets your needs.

Comment: Worked as a charm!